# гетеры и сеттеры js

Tags: javascript, get, set

```
class PrintEditionItem {
  constructor(name, releaseDate, pagesCount) {
    this.name = name
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate
    this.pagesCount = pagesCount
    this.state = 100
    this.type = null
  }
  fix() {
    this.state *= 1.5
  }
  set newState(state) {
    return this.state = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, this.state))
  }
  get newState() {
    return this.state
  }
}
```

Добрый вечер
Подскажите, значение this.state по умолчанию 100, вызов функции fix() должен увеличивать значение на 1,5, как через геттер и сеттер произвести проверку получившегося значения?

Comment: А чем не нравится проверка в сеттере?

Comment: Я если честно не понимаю такой записи, можно ведь сделать так: `this.state = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, this.state))` и всё.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Вы не меняете значение `this.state`

Comment: @EzioMercer только что сам заметил :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 как перфекционист я должен писать - `Math.max(0, Math.min(this.state, 100))`. А то ваш вариант мне глаза режет. :)

Comment: поправил, но как сделать чтобы при выполнении fix также проводилась проверка через условие в set?

Comment: А почему же она не проводится? Разве вы не задаёте значение у `this.state`? Это ведь и есть `set`'инг пропорции.

Comment: @NNL993 
`const sherlock = new PrintEditionItem(
 "Полное собрание повестей и рассказов о Шерлоке Холмсе в одном томе",
 2019,
 1008
);

console.log(sherlock.state); //100
sherlock.fix();
console.log(sherlock.state); //100
`ну при вызове выдает 150 вместо 100

Comment: В чём смысл `fix`-а если у вас изначальное значение 100, умножив на 1.5 вы хотите не выходить за пределы 100 и присвоить обратно 100. У вас что-то может напрямую менять `this.score` или в чём логика всего этого? Мне кажется вы явно что-то намудрили

Answer (score 0):

Смысл `get` и `set` в том, чтобы ограничить значение какого-то свойства. Их смысл пропадает, если

1. это свойство публичное,
2. вы используйте это свойство вместо `get` и `set`

Правильно будет так:

```js
class PrintEditionItem {
  #state;
  get newState() {
    return this.#state;
  }
  set newState(value) {
    this.#state = Math.max(0, Math.min(value, 100));
  }
  fix() {
    this.newState *= 1.5;
  }
}
```

Comment: `get newState(value)`? :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 ой. Кажется я переборщил с алкоголем. :)